# files_get_contents give error with twitter

Tags: php, twitter

thanks !

In php, I would like to know if a twitter user exist.
For that, I try to recover the content of the url :

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$_GET['search']);
$jsonObject = json_decode($json);
```

Where $_GET['search'] = is the name of the user passed in the URL.

But the problem is that if someone give a username which don't exist I got an error.

On php.net, they say that file_get_contents return false if there is an error.

I tried to do in a condition :

```
if(file_get_contents("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$_GET['search']) != false){
    // do my stuff 
}
else{
    // say that this username don't exists
}
```

But when I try this code, I got a big orange warning code which says :

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=A_Wrong_User_Name) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP
```

So I could I remove the error and just check if the twitter user exists or not.
I he exists, I want to get the content of the page with file_get_contents, if not, I want to display that the user doesn't exist.

Thanks for help !

Comment: `failed to open stream` mostly means there is no internet connectivity or the link does not exist.

Comment: Yes Internet works. It's not a problem of conection but a problem of getting the content without have an error

Comment: try to `var_dump("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$_GET['search'])` before `file_get_contents()`. Maybe your request string has some mistype or unescaped characters.

Comment: The answer below answered to my qestion, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use CURL instead of `file_get_contents` :

```
<?php
 $username = "user";

 $url="http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show/".$username.".xml";

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

 curl_exec($ch);
 $header = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
 curl_close($ch);

 if( $header == "404" )
 {
 //it does not exist
 }else{
 //it exists
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain why CURL is recommended?

Comment: It's works! I don't know CURL but thanks you I will analyse more you're code. And yes, why CURL iis better than file_get_contents ?

Comment: You got an error because Twitter answer to PHP that the requested page does not exists (404 Not Found error); and PHP throw an error. However, with CURL, your are at a lower level, and if CURL receives a 404 it tells you so instead of throwing an error :)